# How narrow union of object types when the discriminating field has overlap?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, discriminated-union

I have a type below:

```
type Animal = {
  kind: 'cat';
  params: string;
} | {
  kind: 'dog';
  params: number[];
} | {
  kind: string;
  params: Record<string, string>
}
```

When I'm trying to narrowing down the `Animal` type using switch, it couldn't narrow down to specific object type.

```
switch (animal.kind) {
  case 'cat':
    console.log(animal.params.toUpper())  // Error: animal.params is a type of `string | Record<string, string>`
    break;
  case 'dog':
    console.log(animal.params.length)
    break;
  default:
    console.log("animal is an object");
}
```

But this is not working. In the first `case` it thinks params is `string | Record<string, string>`.

I understand it's because `string` and `"cat"` has overlap, but how can I make this narrowing happen?

Comment: This doesn't fix the error but it should be `toUpper` => `toUpperCase`

Comment: You can't because `{ kind: 'cat', params: { abc: 'def' } }` is a perfectly valid `Animal`, which would then crash at runtime.

Comment: This is currently a design limitation as per [ms/TS#42876](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42876#issuecomment-783609507) because you can't represent "all `string` values except `"cat"` and `"dog"`" as a type.  You'll have to work around this, possibly with a user-defined type guard function as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mM1XQm).  Does this address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please @jcalz mention me if you reply, or I won't be notified).

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the comment, while information for narrowing is enough, it seems that is a design limitation as you said. I'll wait to see if anyone else comments more on this.

Comment: Okay, well if you do decide you want to see my answer, let me know.

Comment: @jcalz I really appreciate if you add your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As @jcalz mentioned in the comments of the question, It seems that this is a typescript Design Limitation.

Base on the [comment here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42876#issuecomment-783609507), Typescript needs to do something like negated types (`string` - `cat` - ...) which Typescript is not designed desecrate unions like that.